# Setting colors for ls in git bash on windows

Tags: mingw32, github-for-windows

I have installed GitHub for Windows recently and am using the git bash prompt - the one thing that is bugging me right now is when I type LS all directories are listed in blue.

How do I change my git bash shell so that when I type LS the directories are listed in a different color to blue?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

This is not specifically a git issue but more the shell that you are using. On MINGW32 using Git 2.9+:

1. C:\Program Files\Git\etc\**bash.bashrc**

> ```
> # Uncomment to use the terminal colours set in DIR_COLORS        
> eval "$(dircolors -b /etc/DIR_COLORS)"
> ```

2. C:\Program Files\Git\etc\**DIR_COLORS**

`DIR 01;37     # Attribute=bold; Text color=white`

**DIR_COLORS File:**

> ```
> # Below are the color init strings for the basic file types. A color init
> # string consists of one or more of the following numeric codes:
> # Attribute codes:
> # 00=none 01=bold 04=underscore 05=blink 07=reverse 08=concealed
> # Text color codes:
> # 30=black 31=red 32=green 33=yellow 34=blue 35=magenta 36=cyan 37=white
> # Background color codes:
> # 40=black 41=red 42=green 43=yellow 44=blue 45=magenta 46=cyan 47=white
> #NORMAL 00    # no color code at all
> #FILE 00      # regular file: use no color at all 
> RESET 0       # reset to "normal" color 
> DIR 01;37     # directory 
> LINK 01;36    # symbolic link.  (If you set this to 'target' instead of a
>               # numerical value, the color is as for the file pointed to.)
> ```

Also see the following posts:

- http://linux-sxs.org/housekeeping/lscolors.html
- http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man5/dir_colors.5.html
- http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_dircolors.htm

For older version of Git, the `bash_profile` in `Git_Installation\etc` folder got the colors to change:

```
LS_COLORS='di=1:fi=0:ln=31:pi=5:so=5:bd=5:cd=5:or=31:mi=0:ex=35:*.rpm=90'
export LS_COLORS
alias ls='ls -F --color --show-control-chars'
```

Answer (score 8):

Check if you have the file: %USERPROFILE%\.minttyrc
In that file you can configure the RGB values for console colors.
I use the following to have colors easy to read in a dark background:

```
BoldBlack=128,128,128
Red=255,64,40
BoldRed=255,128,64
Green=64,200,64
BoldGreen=64,255,64
Yellow=190,190,0
BoldYellow=255,255,64
Blue=0,128,255
BoldBlue=128,160,255
Magenta=200,64,255
BoldMagenta=255,128,255
Cyan=64,190,190
BoldCyan=128,255,255
White=200,200,200
BoldWhite=255,255,255
```

Comment: Thanks man, I was confused between xterm and mintty. Also, to add, there is a tool to make this scheme: http://ciembor.github.io/4bit/#

Comment: This is not what the OP asked but it did help me

Answer (score 3):

I was able to modify `DIR_COLORS` under `/c/Program\ Files/Git/etc` just by adding `;47` to line 49:

was

```
DIR 01;34
```

and now is

```
DIR 01;34;47
```

So now the directories are listed with a white background and much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to use GIT on Windows ... but you should be able to adjust text colors with "git-config":

- http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration

There is also a (hidden?) .gitconfig file you should be able to edit directly:

- http://mohundro.com/blog/2010/02/04/some-tips-on-using-git-with-windows/

Finally, this link has some good tips:

- [In Git Bash on Windows 7, Colors display as code when running Cucumber or rspec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921556/in-git-bash-on-windows-7-colors-display-as-code-when-running-cucumber-or-rspec)