# How to apply syntax highlighting for git-bash code in markdown(using jekyll theme) files?

Tags: jekyll, syntax-highlighting, jekyll-theme

I want to apply syntax highlighting to git bash code like this:

[Please click this image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qqgah.png)

I'm using this following code:

````
    ```gitㅤ
    diff --git a/fourth.py b/fourth.py
    index 13cc618..4c8cfb6 100644
    --- a/fourth.py
    +++ b/fourth.py
    @@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
     print('hello')
    +print('git')

    -print(1)
    -
    -print('bye')
    \ No newline at end of file
    +print('bye')
    +print('20000')
    \ No newline at end of file

```ㅤ
````

not working for use keyword such as github, Github, vim, diff, bash, etc. instead of `git`.

How can I do this?

example: if python, instead of git:

```py
print('hello world!')
```

this method is not working for git-code.

Comment: hi @Iwon J, welcome to stackoverflow! have you read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14049896/setting-colors-for-ls-in-git-bash-on-windows ?

Comment: Can you elaborate? There's no such thing as a "git bash code", so we need to try to understand what you're talking about. What you have shown is a (colored) output produced by `git diff` — on of the Git commands. Now what exactly is your problem? _Where_ do you want to have "syntax highlighting"? There are so many contexts such a diff output may be displayed…

Comment: Or, you may be you wanted to say something like "The output of `git` commands is colored when it's rendered in a Git Bash window. I would like the output of other random commands to be colored as well"?

Comment: Hello, I want to apply syntax highlighting(color..ing) to my code in jekyll-themed blog, but not working for git-code, unlike python or javascript, etc.

Comment: Thanks. While I still have no idea what you call "git-code" (I'm not sure such thing exists) at least I've managed to retag your question properly. Hope you'll get help from Jekyll users.

Comment: Have you tried ```shell?

Comment: Of course, (bash = zsh = sh = shell have same effects) but it's not working..

Answer (score 0):

In Markdown, when you want to specify a code block (as you have done), you will use the triple backticks (```) to start and end the string you wish formatted as "code." In many Markdown renderers (notably, those following GitHub's implementation of Markdown), you may provide a string ("js", "c++", "html") which represents a language, granting syntax highlighting to the code block.

"git" is not a language, nor an option which works with the above-mentioned syntax highlighting feature. There is no syntax highlighting feature, that I'm aware of, for git diff's format.

You could use triple-backticks followed by "python" (```python). This will provide syntax highlighting to the Python portion but it will be polluted by parsing the non-Python at the top and in the middle of git diff's output text.