# Why is the output from comman prompt broken?

Tags: php, cmd, laravel-artisan

The results in cmd are broken as shown below

[image: cmd error]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Artisan showing inserting "32m", "34;4m" and similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537366/artisan-showing-inserting-32m-344m-and-similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmd does not support ANSI codes. Run the Laravel scripts with `--no-ansi` to fix the output.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt638032(v=vs.85).aspx (Applies to the Anniversary Update for Windows 10) Console is now VT100.