# Unknown characters in serve command

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

`php artisan serve`[Why does my command have unkown characters ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2Ik9.png)

[I am using cmd, i have read a lot of stuff but i cant find anyone having same problems with me :3 i can't even upload a photo here newbie problems hehe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUE2o.png)

Comment: [32mLaravel development server started on http://localhost:8000/[39m

Comment: what is your command, Samson?

Comment: @JONASVINCENTSamson Use a terminal that understands ANSI/VT colors - ["[32m" represents an escape sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Comment: here is my command "php artisan serve"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Artisan showing inserting "32m", "34;4m" and similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33537366/artisan-showing-inserting-32m-344m-and-similar)

Comment: Also, please search first..

Comment: sorry hehe, i did try hehe, but i wasn't able to find it

Comment: Why do i have this problem? i am using a windows 10, which is 64 bit, and i installed 64 bit git too ? huhu need help

Answer (score 1):

As the link that @user2864740 suggests, your terminal is escaping characters that result in the weird codes being displayed (in your case these are to colour the output text).

Your images suggest you are using Windows CMD, try using GitBash. For me this doesn't result in any special characters, however if you still face this issue then update the terminal options to xterm-256 (rather than xterm which is the default) as is suggested in the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34523117/1739852), and in their source [here](http://www.techhelp.pw/git-bash-using-laravel-artisan-displays-escaped-characters/).

For reference, this is what I get when I run `php artisan serve` in GitBash:

[image]