# Garbled text after anniversary update

Tags: windows, laravel, cmd, composer-php, laravel-artisan

After updating to Windows 10 anniversary update(1607), the artisan text in Windows CMD becomes garbled.

Is there any way to fix this?

I've tried the legacy console option but not working.

[image]

Comment: read some answers here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5921556/in-git-bash-on-windows-7-colors-display-as-code-when-running-cucumber-or-rspec. I have got my fixed with unsetting TERM environment variable on git bash when having the same trouble

Comment: @naneri I'm sorry, after reading I still don't understand. I'm not using Git Bash but Windows CMD.

Comment: Hi, instead of downvoting, can you please explain any fix or workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the anniversary update disabled the ansi color.

Let's just wait for the fix.

For now there's a workaround using `--no-ansi` flag when calling the command.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19520

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly, if you pipe the colorized output of the command to a *output.txt* file and then use `type output.txt` it shows the colors.

It seems like the problem arises from the way cmd is treating output `ESC` character from programs after the Anniversary Update. (Although, they have added this feature in [Insiders Build](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2016/09/22/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console/))

**Workaround** use [Cmder](https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder), it's a good alternative to CMD and it still shows colors and of course Unicode characters.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But Instead of using 3rd party, Powershell works fine but I still prefer using CMD..

Comment: Sure. I didn't try the PowerShell, should check it out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was to set the Backwards-Compatibility of the cmd.exe to Windows 7. After that it worked again.

Comment: Hi, where did you set that? My cmd.exe does not have Compatibility tab

Comment: This is weird. I can't find it anymore :(

But what is more weird: It works now with Legacymode enabled.